# Tally conditional column on Reports

Tags: reporting

I have a report which retrieves from X Object with 2 fields called below. The first one is XObject Name and the second is a custom date field. Problem is we need to add a tally based on that custom date field which is subjected to conditions as well.

1. If date is equals to last month, Mark it as **New Applicant**
2. If date is not equal to last month, Mark it as **Existing Applicant**

[image]

Is it possible to have a conditional logic on this field on this report? I am wondering if this kind of output is possible. Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Row-Level Formula](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=5&language=en_US). Row-level formulas allow you to add calculated data to your report, including the use of conditional logic. Here, you would use a Text-type Row Level Formula to show "New Applicant" or "Existing Applicant" based on your date fields.

You can then group the report by your Row-Level Formula, which will provide you with record counts and subtotals for each of the two groups.

Comment: David Reed you are a legend man. Thank you kind sir!